# In flex model element with line break cuts off previous element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In flex model long text element with line break cuts off previous element in row.  But if text element doesn't have long text everything is good.
What I'm doing wrong?

```css
.franchisePlaceAverage {
 width: 450px;
 border: 4px solid #93d5ab;
}
.franchisePlaceAverage .row {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
  align-items:center;
  margin: 20px 0
}
.franchisePlaceAverage .star{
 width: 20px;
 height: 19px;
 margin: 10px 28px;
 background: tomato;
}
.franchisePlaceAverage .text {
}
```

```html
<div class="franchisePlaceAverage">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="text">Some long text here Some long text here Some long text here Some long text here </div>
  </div>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="text">Some short text here </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? have them in 50/50 columns or what? you called the element "row" and gave it a width of 100% so it looks like it's behaving correctly as far as I can perceive your intentions to be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox is trying to fit all your content in and so is reducing the with of the first item (`.star`). You can prevent this by using `flex-shrink:0;` or by forcing a min-width on the element.

```css
.franchisePlaceAverage {
 width: 450px;
 border: 4px solid #93d5ab;
}
.franchisePlaceAverage .row {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
  align-items:center;
  margin: 20px 0
}
.franchisePlaceAverage .star{
 width: 20px;
    flex-shrink:0;/* don't shrink me */
    /* min-width: 20px; would also work */
 height: 19px;
 margin: 10px 28px;
 background: tomato;
}
.franchisePlaceAverage .text {
}
```

```html
<div class="franchisePlaceAverage">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="text">Some long text here Some long text here Some long text here Some long text here </div>
  </div>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="text">Some short text here </div>
 </div>
</div>
```